# Is it possible to create a new sheet and append values to it using a single call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate()?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

Up until now I have been calling sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate() and then sheets.spreadsheets.values.append() in order to put values on the newly created sheet. I was wondering if I could insert a second request within the "requests: []" when calling the batchUpdate since it can hold more than one request at I time, in order to append the values right after creating the new sheet without having to make an additional api call of sheets.spreadsheets.values.append() to be able to put values in it.

I have been fiddling around and I feel I am close enough, but got to the following:

```
"requests": [
      {
        "addSheet": {
          "properties": {
            "title": "Prueba",
            "sheetId": 9
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "appendCells": {
          "rows": [
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": {
                    "stringValue": "Work"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "fields": "userEnteredValue",
          "sheetId": 9
        }
      }
    ]
```

The problem here is that since "sheetId" will be unknown until the sheet gets created and given a sheetId value, I am force to give myself an id for the appendCells to be able to find the sheet I just created. Is there any documentation/idea on how to achieve this without having to manually specify the sheetId myself?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the reason that `"sheetId": 9` cannot be used in `addSheet`?

Comment: If you are using node.js, can't you just get your script to dynamically create each "appendCells" object? You always need to specify the sheet anyway, usually in the range name i.e. `Sheet1!A1:D5`, if you don't it just defaults to the first `sheetId`. See this sample for instance - https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing#write_to_multiple_ranges